# Is it possible to know that an app was launched by clicking on a link?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am aware that it is possible to determine whether an app was launched from a push notification by adding a flag to the intent, but is it possible to know that an app was launched by clicking on a (URL) link? The only idea that comes to my mind is to add something like `deepLink=true` to the URL itself and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the URI of the deeplink by using `intent.dataString`